# how can I save jupyter notebook running on a server?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to save the whole notebook (i.e mynotebook.ipynb). What's the command that let me save the notebook on the server? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you mean by save "on the server", but you can export it as a ipynb via "File"->"Download as".  You can also save it to the file you're working on by clickign the floppy disk icon, or going to "File"->"Save and checkpoint"

[Where to find "Download as" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p32OK.png)

Comment: I am working on Ipython on spark cluster. There is no web interface. It's only either majic commands or python commands. Thanks.

Comment: You mean you're in terminal IPython? This is not a notebook, but you can save the command history as a notebook by running `%notebook filename`.